# django: how to prohibit DB access in a function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Context:** our project has DRF serializers spanning ForeignKey relationships. So when I get a ListView of my objects I get an extra DB hit for every object, i.e. a list of 100 items gets me 100 extra DB queries. Not good. To fix this, I use `select_related`/`prefetch_related` in my views to do the necessary joins before serializing.

**Problem**: It is hard to keep up with all the `select_related`s in the views, especially when different developers work on the same features and serializers. So I was wondering if there is a way to prohibit access to DB in a function (be it view or serializer method etc). The first idea was to wrap it in a decorator that counts `connection.queries` but this counter is always empty in production (when `DEBUG=False`).

So is there another way to count db queries when `DEBUG` is `False`?

Comment: I don't think you're approaching this the right way. I would write unit tests that check the number of queries and fix the code when too many queries are performed. What do achieve with prohibiting db access in a function? An application that doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to decorate methods and classes with a limit on the database queries seems a totally wrong approach to me. If you want to keep a tight watch on the number of database queries performed by your views, you should use unit tests.

Django has a test assertion to count queries:

```
with self.assertNumQueries(2):
    response = self.client.get(my_url)
```

which will make sure there are just 2 db queries for fetching this particular view.

Comment: yeah - i think this is a better idea indeed. Thought of this myself too. Thanks!